# Nest 0.12.0.0 missing CreateIndexRaw

Tags: nest

I'm trying to upgrade from Nest .10 to .12, but don't see what call I need to substitute for client.CreateIndexRaw("myIndexName", myJsonSettings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use

`client.Raw.IndicesCreatePost("myIndexName", myJsonSettings, nv=>nv);`

myJsonSettings can be a string or anonymous c# object. The last argument is optional but allows you to pass any querystring value you might need.